# Understanding assignment of const reference to non-cost data member

Tags: c++

I am reviewing C++ references any am trying to reason why the following piece of code complies:

```
#include <string>

class Foo {

public:

    Foo(const std::string& label)
        : d_label(label) {}

private:

    std::string d_label;

};

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    Foo("test");
    return 0;
}
```

Here, we are assigning a reference to a const string to a string. In doing so, is a copy of `label` made that is non-const? If so, why is it that we can make a copy of a const object that is itself non-const? Otherwise, what exactly is going on here, in terms of copy constructor/assignment calls?

Comment: I can't get your question. You can make a copy, the copy might be non-const or const; anyway, it has nothing to do with the original object (after being copied).

Comment: not sure if that is your misunderstanding, but in `const int x = 5` it is `x` that is `const` not the value. E.g. `int y = x` is perfectly fine, as well as `y = 3` afterwards. The reference doesnt change that

Comment: Remember, a reference is basically the same as a pointer (that can't be null).   So when you're asking yourself why something with a reference works, try saying "pointer" instead and see if it makes more sense that way.

Comment: "we are assigning a reference to a const string to a string" - no, you're *initializing* a new `std:string` from an existing reference to a `const std::string`. Later on you say, "..we can make a copy of a const object" - operative words there: *"make a copy"*. That's exactly what is happening in the member initialization list, leaving you a modifiable `std::string` as your member. See [#7 from here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).

Answer (score 3):

In C++ the keyword `const` actually means *read-only*. To make a copy of an object, you don't need write access. Therefore, you can copy a `const std::string` into an `std::string`.

Also note, that copying in C++ means making a deep copy by default. This is called *value semantics*. Hence, manipulating the copied string will not do anything to the original string.

Now to your last question: What is going on in the following line?

> ```
> Foo("test");
> ```

The type of `"test"` is `const char[5]`. The compiler searches for a matching constructor of `Foo`. Since `"test"` is implicitly convertible to `std::string` via the

```
basic_string<CharT,Alloc>::basic_string( const CharT * s, const Alloc & a = Alloc() );
```

constructor, this conversion will be performed, i. e. a temporary `std::string` is constructed from `"test"`. A const reference to this temporary is then passed to the constructor

```
Foo::Foo( const std::string & label );
```

This constructor in turn calls `std::string`s copy constructor in order to construct the `d_label` member of `Foo`:

```
basic_string<CharT,Alloc>::basic_string( const basic_string & other );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here no *assignments* take place. `d_label(label)` *initializes* the variable `d_label` with `label` which subsequently ends up calling [*copy constructor*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) of `string` type.

Let's have a closer look:

- `Foo("test");` initializes `const std::string& label` with `"test"` which its type is `const char[5]`
- Here a string reference (`label`) is getting initialized with a value having type `const char[5]`. This initialization is valid since `"test"` through [decaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) to `const char *` can be passed to one of `string` constructors which gets a `const char *`.
- Now `label` is a reference to a real string object storing `"test"`.
- Then, `d_label(label)` initializes `Foo::d_label` with the object referred to by `label`.
- At this point *copy constructor* of `string` type is called and constructs the `Foo::d_label`.

Comment: @VolAnd actually it has type `const char[5]`

Answer (score 1):

C++ offers both reference semantics and value semantics: Objects have values, and then you can take references to objects.

> ```
> std::string d_label
> ```

`d_label` is an object holding a string value. It is considered to own the bytes holding the string as a memory resource. This notion of ownership rationalizes using `d_label` as an interface to modify the string.

> ```
> const std::string& label
> ```

`label` is a read-only reference to a string. This is not quite the same as "a reference to a `const` string." It refers to an object that may be (and probably is) not `const`.

> ```
> : d_label(label)
> ```

This initializes `d_label` with the content of `label` using a copy constructor. You may then do what you like with the copy. You know that the process of copying won't modify the underlying object of `label` because `label` was declared `const &`.